# JDO doesn't create Owned Entities in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Hey guys, my question is about persisting an entity in JDO.  I have created a class, StoredOPDSFeed, whose members persist correctly.  However, none of its member objects persist correctly.  The class is as follows:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class StorableOPDSFeed implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private String primaryKey;

@Persistent
private String locale;

@Persistent
private Date parseDate;

@Persistent
private String title;

@Persistent
private String href;

@Persistent
@Element(dependent = "true")
private ArrayList<OPDSEntry> entries;

@Persistent
@Element(dependent = "true")
private ArrayList<OPDSLink> links = new ArrayList<OPDSLink>();

@Persistent
@Embedded
private SearchDescription searchDescription;

@Persistent
private boolean isStart = false;

@Persistent
@Element(dependent = "true")
private ArrayList<OPDSFacetGroup> facet_groups = new ArrayList<OPDSFacetGroup>();

... and accessors, etc.
}
```

All of the simple members such as locale, title, href, etc persist correctly.  However, all of the complex ones such as searchDescription do not appear in the datastore.  There is no reference to them whatsoever, no foreign key, nothing.  It's like they are completely ignored.  Does anyone have any idea why?

Per request, here is the code for OPDSLink:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class OPDSLink implements Serializable { 
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
private String encodedKey;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Persistent
private String href;

@Persistent
private String rel;

@Persistent
private String type;

@Persistent
private String price;

@Persistent
private String currency;

@Persistent
private String dcformat;

@Persistent
private String title;
... and accessors, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GAE JDO documentation states that in one-to-one relationships both involved entities require a key field.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_One_Relationships

If the other entity is embedded as intended in your example, the other class (e.g. SearchDescription) requires a @EmbeddedOnly annotation:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Embedded_Classes

In general I found the the following blog interview a good starting point to see what the GAE JDO implementation supports and what not (especially in comparison to third party frameworks such as Objectify and Twig):
http://borglin.net/gwt-project/?page_id=604

Comment: While I appreciate the link, unfortunately that comment does not apply at all.  Most of the members I'm referring to are owned one-to-many relationships, and as you can see, the owned one-to-one relationship in the class is already set to Embedded.  This did cause the owned one-to-one relationship to appear, however, so this answer does at least explain that behaviour, so I appreciate that.  The main question, however, is unanswered.

Comment: Can you show us the code for class OPDSLink and OPDSFacetGroup? Also have you tried removing @Element(dependent = "true")?

Comment: Absolutely - I added the OPDSLink definition as it is the simpler of the two classes.  My original code did not contain @Element(dependent = "true") and it did not work.  I added the "@Element(dependent = "true")" to see if it would make a difference (and because in this case the OPDSLink truly is dependent).   Thanks for you time!

Comment: I tried reproducing your example only for StorableOPDSFeed and OPDSLink without implementing Serializable. It complained about the primaryKey in StorableOPDSFeed being of type String. After changing it to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key it worked for me.
I stripped your example down to the essential fields/classes, so there might be something else in your code preventing it from working. Try starting off from the example given in the Docs and extending it to your needs.

Comment: Very interesting.  Meanwhile, I rewrote everything using Twig from your first link and it all started working.  Considerably faster and easier than JDO, so I'll mark this accepted just for turning me on to Twig, thanks! :)